# Xaml designer on VS2013 doesn`t work

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, designer, visual-studio-2013

When I open xaml in Windows Phone project there is shows error:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[3392] Designer sudenly stoped running!
```

After click "reload page" button shows another error:

> System.InvalidCastException    Specified cast is not valid.
>          in MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>          in MS.Internal.XcpImports.DependencyProperty_GetDefaultValue(DependencyProperty
>   dp, DependencyObject propertyOwner, UInt32 propertyOwnerTypeId)
>          in System.Windows.CoreDependencyProperty.GetMetadata(UInt32 propertyOwnerTypeId)
>          in System.Windows.CoreDependencyProperty.GetMetadataCore(Type forType)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightDependencyPropertyImplementation.GetDefaultValue(IType
>   targetType)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.DependencyPropertyReferenceStep.GetDefaultValue(IType
>   targetType)
>         in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightDesignTimeProperties.ResolveImplementation(IPlatformMetadata
>   platformMetadata, DesignTimePropertyId neutralProperty, IType
>   declaringType, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightDesignTimeProperties.RegisterProperty(IPropertyId
>   neutralPropertyKey, IType declaringType, PropertyChangedCallback
>   callback)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightMiscDesignTimeProperties.Initialize(SilverlightDesignTimeProperties
>   designTimeProperties)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightDesignTimeProperties..ctor(IPlatformTypes
>   platformMetadata)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightPlatformMetadata.Initialize()
>          in Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightPlatform.Initialize()
>          in Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformCreatorBase.CreatePlatform(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver
>   referenceAssemblyResolver)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject
>   project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem
>   sourceItem)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c_*DisplayClass13.b*_12(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass3`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__2()
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>       System.InvalidCastException    Specified cast is not valid.
>       Server stack trace: 
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32
>   lineNumber)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String
>   methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>         in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject
>   targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality,
>   ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath,
>   Int32 lineNumber)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken
>   remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject
>   remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor
>   remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
>          in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.*PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>          in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          in System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          in System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject
>   remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor
>   remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor,
>   RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
>          in  Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c*_DisplayClass19.b_*18(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c*_DisplayClass5`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__4(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0()
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>       System.InvalidCastException
>       Specified cast is not valid.
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>         in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName,
>   String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>         in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>         in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1
>   targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState,
>   String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1
>   targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState,
>   String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
>          in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>         in Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)

I tried to reinstall VS2013, Silverligth 5 SDK, but it didn`t help.
Rebuilding project also didn`t help.